# RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory when .append?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, append

I have 50 clients but I would like to train each 5 clients seperately and save their weights in `w_locals` after that I would like to save all the weights in `w_totals`

```
w_totals = []
for iter in range(epochs):
  
    w_locals = [w_glob for i in range(client_5)]
    
    for idxs_task in range(task_num):
        
        dataset = load_data() 
        
        for client_idx in range(client_5):
                   
            dataloader_train = load_data_train()
            w = train(copy.deepcopy(net_glob).to(device), dataloader_train) 
            w_locals[client_idx] = copy.deepcopy(w)
                      
        
        w_totals.append(copy.deepcopy(w_locals))
```

I'm sure that the error come when I add this line `w_totals.append(copy.deepcopy(w_locals))`
So how can I resolve the problem and

Answer (score 0):

Try to transfer the weight to cpu first and then save the weight. Or if you can, save each model to hard drive and save the path to each weight. If you copy the weight directly from GPU, sometime the unused one will not be handled by garbage collector, and the new one is still stay on gpu, which will take up space.